# asp.net mvc core add anchor tag in success function in ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

It's not a working properly anchor tag in the success function of ajax in jquery. Button clicked but not perform action.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data.models, function (index, value) {
                        $('#Teacher_table tbody').append("<tr><td> <a asp-action='Action_name' asp-route-id="+value.Id +">Edit</a></td></tr>");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: You have a typo, "Contrroler" on the `url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Contrroler")",` line.

Comment: Ohh yeah  I correct this, but anchor tag is not working

Comment: is the value of asp-route-id rendering correctly on the page, is there a proper action in the controller to handle the route in question and the id value?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1#asp-route-value

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution to this problem.

> asp-action is not work in success function in asp.net MVC core. So use this code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data.models, function (index, value) {
                        $('#Teacher_table tbody').append("<tr><td><a href='/Controller/Action?id=" + Id + "'>Anchor Name</a></td></tr>");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```